# how to extend range with end() iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stl-algorithm

(not sure that is correct task)
I'm writing an algorithm in stl style related with classic sorting.
prototype is:

```
  template<typename RAIter>
  void Algo(RAIter first, RAIter last) {
  ....
    size_t size = std::distance(first, last);
    RAIter midIter =first;
    std::advance(midIter, size / 2 - 1);

    Algo(first, midIter);
    Algo(midIter + 1, last);
    ....
 }
```

but it doesn't work correctly for me because ,
initially it gets the range like:
vector v;
Algo(v.begin(), v.end());
however , internally, in recursive call the subrange doesn't contain end() element.

what is a typical technique in this case?

Comment: You're being inconsistent within the algorithm. You call it with the end being excluded, but you call it recursively with the end being both included and excluded.

Comment: Actually the question is- how to add end() element for internal calls

Comment: If you have different contracts on the internal calls than on the user calls, you need a different function.

Comment: Question: Why does the recursive call need the `end()` element?  I can't think of any classic sorting algorithm that needs that information.

Comment: The passing end element is a usual practice in stl, where all algorithms work with range [first, last)

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose two options.

1. (Preferred) Make the algorithm so that internally it doesn't need inclusion of `last`. In your case it can be done like this:

   ```
   template<typename RAIter>
   void Algo(RAIter first, RAIter last) {
       ....
       size_t size = std::distance(first, last);
       if (size <= 1) {
            // special processing of single-item or empty range
            return;
       }

       RAIter midIter =first;

       std::advance(midIter, size / 2);

       Algo(first, midIter); // midIter not included
       Algo(midIter, last);  // it's included here instead
   }
   ```
2. Make a separate function which expects ranges with `last` included:

   ```
   template<typename RAIter>
   void AlgoImpl(RAIter first, RAIter last) {
       ....
       // looks like this is more correct:
       // size_t size = std::distance(first, last) + 1;
       size_t size = std::distance(first, last);
       RAIter midIter =first;
       std::advance(midIter, size / 2 - 1); // and here "- 1" seems wrong 

       AlgoImpl(first, midIter);
       AlgoImpl(midIter + 1, last);
       ....
   }

   template<typename RAIter>
   void Algo(RAIter first, RAIter last) {
       if (first == last) {
           return;
       }
       AlgoImpl(first, last - 1);
   }
   ```

Comment: E.g. Container has 6 elements. With using end() for initial call, distance returns 6, but on the next step, it returns 2 instead of expected 3, that's clear, because initial call contains 7 elements with end, but next call gets 3 elements only and no end.

Comment: @amigo421 Note `std::advance(midIter, size / 2);` not `size / 2 - 1`. BTW `size/2 - 1` is wrong in both cases, I just didn't edit the second one.

Comment: @amigo421 but probably you don't wont to divide the range into equal parts, who knows

Comment: That is a learning example for merge sorting (for internal sort) , your second way looks ok for me, but, of course, I'd prefer to implement this way within single function